# Why does action button in docked widget when docked with (self.addDockWidget(Qt.RightDockWidgetArea, self.dock) doesn't work in QMdiArea?

Tags: pyqt5, mdi, qdockwidget, qmdiarea

The button action on dock widget doesn't activate or work when docked on right, left, top or bottom in Mdi but it works without MdiArea.

I tested without MdiArea on a tab widget and it works fine there but with Mdi it doesn't work.